# The image moved with a float change leaves 'sewage content' (contentediable element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, contenteditable

I have a particular error when I change the float attribute to an image in an editable container.
Look at this image to understand the error:

[image: Bug image float on content editable]

The first image is without the float attribute, the second has the float attribute 'left'.
The float attribute changes with javascript.
How can I fix this bug and bring it all around the image?
The code of this bug is:

```js
function right(){
    document.getElementById('img').style.float = 'right';
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width:800px" onclick="right()">
    <img id="img" src="http://imgsrv.worldstart.com/antunes_flower_photography_4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

This problem is best seen with mozilla firefox

Comment: "How can I fix this bug and bring it all around the image?" - What exactly is "it"?

Comment: I'm trying to see the situation of the first flower I posted before clicking even after the click

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Seems to work fine in 11

Comment: This bug in on Mozilla Firefox last version, i dont' see it in chrome and IE.